# Why do I have an error "column "content_type_id" does not exist" in Django?

Tags: django, django-models

I'm trying to create a Comment class so that I can comment any type of object with it. I have found a solution here : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/contenttypes/
However, it didn't work. (I must admit that i didn't understand everything about the content_type and object_id they used, I just copied the code from their page)

Here is my model :

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
    author = models.CharField(max_length=200, default="userPasDef")
    text = models.TextField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def publish(self):
        self.created_date = timezone.now()
        self.author = "userPasDef"
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text
```

Here is the error :

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/computer/Documents/virtualenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: column "content_type_id" of relation "Application_comment" does not exist
LINE 1: INSERT INTO "Application_comment" ("content_type_id", "objec...

But I don't have any "content_type_id" in my model... 
I can run makemigrations, migrate and runserver, but each time I try to post a comment on my site this error appears.
What could have caused this problem ?

Thanks ! :)

---

Edit :
"Show the output of python manage.py showmigrations "

Application
 [X] 0001_initial

(I tried deleting all my database and previous migrations to reset them but it didn't solve the problem)

"and any migrations files for your app that contains Comment"

```
        migrations.CreateModel(
        name='Comment',
        fields=[
            ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
            ('object_id', models.PositiveIntegerField()),
            ('author', models.CharField(default='userPasDef', max_length=200)),
            ('text', models.TextField()),
            ('created_date', models.DateTimeField(default=django.utils.timezone.now)),
            ('content_type', models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to='contenttypes.ContentType')),
        ],
    ),
```

Comment: are you sure that you don't have pending migrations?

Comment: Show the output of `python manage.py showmigrations <yourapp>`, and any migrations files for your app that contains `Comment`.

Comment: Edited my post :) And yes, I'm sure I don't have pending migrations !

Comment: "ContentType" is your model or you take it from the django default? Because if you che migrations, there is an app called "contenttypes" and maybe can create confict

Comment: I took ContentType from the django defaults (from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType) :)

Answer (score 2):

So, for anyone who would have the same problem as me, the problem was not in my models but in my database. I dropped all the tables in postgre, made my migrations again and everything was working. I really shouldn't have deleted all these migration files (I didn't know they were so important). Django is lost without them because he can't remember the current state of the database. :)